# API additional id,

Tags: api, limesurvey

I'm trying to get data from my limesurvey and wonder why in API request I need to pass `id: 1` as the third body parameter.

```
{method:'get_session_key',params:['myusername','mypassword'],id:1}
```

If I omit `id` or pass `id:0`, I will get the response data with an empty string. I can put any positive and negative integers there and I don't know exactly why it is required.

I'm following instructions on [RemoteControl 2 API](https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API)

Answer (score 0):

That's the request id.

On the jsonRPCClient (component outside of LS) code it is fixed to 1.
I think it is part of a standard to use notifications, which are not used on LS API.

So, just fix it to 1 :)